# How to connect Bluetooth device (headphones) to another computer without an access to currently connected one?

Tags: bluetooth

I have BT headphones, which remember to which computer they were connected. To connect them to another computer, I need to disconnect them first. Which means I need to open the first computer and manually disconnect them from it.

Is this the normal behaviour of BT?

Suppose I have 100 computers and mobile phones and I forgot, to which device I have connected my phones last time. What to do? Should I try each? Or maybe I forgot the previous device in my car. Should I really go down to the parking to disconnect?

Is there another procedure to connect phones to the very computer I am sitting at?

Comment: Is this normal behaviour of BT?   ........   It is for my BT devices.  I must un-pair before moving.

Comment: it is not normal for wireless devices, it's bad design, if it is normal to BT, it means BT has bad design

Comment: There should be a way to reset the headphones so they forget the original pairing and can pair to a new devices. Check the manual (you have it, right?)

Comment: Unpairing is a unilateral action. Either side can do it at any time without contact to the other side.

Answer (score 0):

For headphones unless you have multipoint, it is normal.

Please see this article for ordinary setups.

[Move Headphones](https://www.sony.com/electronics/support/wireless-headphones-bluetooth-headphones/wh-1000xm4/articles/00249936)

> When you connect headphones to a device, the music playback (Media
> audio) and the phone call function (Call audio) are connected
> simultaneously. Most headphones allow multiple Bluetooth® connections
> to audio devices; however, to switch sources, you need to go into the
> Bluetooth settings, disconnect the current source, and then connect
> the source you want to use with the headphones.
>
> If your headphones support a multipoint connection, you can switch
> easily between two audio sources without going through the standard
> Bluetooth reconnection process.

Please see this article for Multi Point:

[Multi Point](https://www.soundguys.com/bluetooth-multipoint-explained-28601/)

> Bluetooth multipoint s a feature that allows a single Bluetooth
> headset to maintain simultaneous connections to at least two source
> devices like a laptop and smartphone, and was introduced with the
> release of Bluetooth 4.0, over ten years ago. For it to function, a
> device must support both A2DP and HFP/HSP connections for audio
> streaming and talking, respectively.